# TextMate Edit Bundle Snippet

Tags: conditional-statements, textmate, bundle, textmatebundles

I want to update the HTML bundle so that the `head` snippet outputs `<meta charset="utf-8">` instead of `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` if the doctype is HTML5. How?

This is what it looks like now in the Bundle Editor:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"${TM_XHTML}>
  <title>${1:${TM_FILENAME/((.+)\..*)?/(?2:$2:Page Title)/}}</title>
  $0
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Textmate allows you to [interpolate shell code into snippets](http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets#interpolated_shell_code). The shell code is evaluated and placed inline. So you could write some Ruby (or some other code: maybe Perl or some funky combination of old-school sed, grep, awk, etc.) that can extract out the doctype. Then [test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28Unix%29) on the result in an if-then block and echo whichever head you'd prefer.